# how can i read a gmail subject with php api?

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

in witch mode a can read the email subject with php api ?

i do this code

```
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

// Print the labels in the user's account.
$user = 'me';


$results = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($user);
foreach($results as $mail){
  $optParamsGet['format'] = 'metadata'; // Display message in payload
  $message = $service->users_messages->get($user, $mail['id'],$optParamsGet);
  $objMessage = $message->getPayload();
  print_r($objMessage[18]['value']);
}
```

i find very difficult use this api with php because there isn't any documentation about the function.
where i can find the comple documentation?
(for example i found getPayload function because i see some example here)

thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have a look at a bare bones response you get when accessing the API with regular http-requests, I think a lot of things will be more clear.

I will [list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) my latest message, and then [get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) the message, and have a look at the response:

**Request**

```
maxResults = 1

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxResults=1
```

**Response**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "150791be31ee4e7b",
   "threadId": "150791be31ee4e7b"
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "05858850367051193217",
 "resultSizeEstimate": 2
}
```

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/150791be31ee4e7b
```

**Response**

```
{
 "id": "150791be31ee4e7b",
 "threadId": "150791be31ee4e7b",
 "labelIds": [
  "INBOX",
  "CATEGORY_SOCIAL",
  "UNREAD"
 ],
 "snippet": "Infinite Elgintensity has uploaded Gym Idiots - The Smith Machine&#39;s Retarded Cousin I have no",
 "historyId": "623043",
 "internalDate": "1445140881000",
 "payload": {
  "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
  "filename": "",
  "headers": [
   {
    "name": "Delivered-To",
    "value": "emtholin@gmail.com"
   },
   {
    "name": "Received",
    "value": "by 10.28.188.5 with SMTP id m5csp628249wmf;        Sat, 17 Oct 2015 21:01:22 -0700 (PDT)"
   },
   {
    "name": "X-Received",
    "value": "by 10.182.28.74 with SMTP id z10mr15179312obg.80.1445140882358;        Sat, 17 Oct 2015 21:01:22 -0700 (PDT)"
   },
   {
    "name": "Return-Path",
    "value": "<3kRkjVgcLDAgvwzmxt66w212jm.kwu1p2ttmB-898Fxiom0.xt20owwotm.kwu@youtube-subscriptions.bounces.google.com>"
   },
   {
    "name": "Received",
    "value": "from mail-ob0-x245.google.com (mail-ob0-x245.google.com. [2607:f8b0:4003:c01::245])        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id l8si12292524oej.1.2015.10.17.21.01.22        for <emtholin@gmail.com>        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);        Sat, 17 Oct 2015 21:01:22 -0700 (PDT)"
   },
   {
    "name": "Received-SPF",
    "value": "pass (google.com: domain of 3kRkjVgcLDAgvwzmxt66w212jm.kwu1p2ttmB-898Fxiom0.xt20owwotm.kwu@youtube-subscriptions.bounces.google.com designates 2607:f8b0:4003:c01::245 as permitted sender) client-ip=2607:f8b0:4003:c01::245;"
   },
   {
    "name": "Authentication-Results",
    "value": "mx.google.com;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of 3kRkjVgcLDAgvwzmxt66w212jm.kwu1p2ttmB-898Fxiom0.xt20owwotm.kwu@youtube-subscriptions.bounces.google.com designates 2607:f8b0:4003:c01::245 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=3kRkjVgcLDAgvwzmxt66w212jm.kwu1p2ttmB-898Fxiom0.xt20owwotm.kwu@youtube-subscriptions.bounces.google.com;       dkim=pass header.i=@youtube.com;       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=youtube.com"
   },
   {
    "name": "Received",
    "value": "by mail-ob0-x245.google.com with SMTP id da8so130023858obb.1        for <emtholin@gmail.com>; Sat, 17 Oct 2015 21:01:22 -0700 (PDT)"
   },
   {
    "name": "X-Received",
    "value": "by 10.107.148.204 with SMTP id w195mr21311032iod.15.1445140881929;        Sat, 17 Oct 2015 21:01:21 -0700 (PDT)"
   },
   {
    "name": "X-Received",
    "value": "by 10.140.238.83 with SMTP id j80mr20061780qhc.2.1445140881732;        Sat, 17 Oct 2015 21:01:21 -0700 (PDT)"
   },
   {
    "name": "Return-Path",
    "value": "<3kRkjVgcLDAgvwzmxt66w212jm.kwu1p2ttmB-898Fxiom0.xt20owwotm.kwu@youtube-subscriptions.bounces.google.com>"
   },
   {
    "name": "Received",
    "value": "from mail-pa0-f72.google.com (mail-pa0-f72.google.com. [209.85.220.72])        by gmr-mx.google.com with ESMTPS id wl2si2608966pab.1.2015.10.17.21.01.21        for <thulle3-0107@pages.plusgoogle.com>        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);        Sat, 17 Oct 2015 21:01:21 -0700 (PDT)"
   },
   {
    "name": "Received-SPF",
    "value": "pass (google.com: domain of 3kRkjVgcLDAgvwzmxt66w212jm.kwu1p2ttmB-898Fxiom0.xt20owwotm.kwu@youtube-subscriptions.bounces.google.com designates 209.85.220.72 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.220.72;"
   },
   {
    "name": "Received",
    "value": "by mail-pa0-f72.google.com with SMTP id da3so25pad.2        for <thulle3-0107@pages.plusgoogle.com>; Sat, 17 Oct 2015 21:01:21 -0700 (PDT)"
   },
   {
    "name": "DKIM-Signature",
    "value": "v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;        d=youtube.com; s=20120806;        h=mime-version:message-id:date:subject:from:to:content-type;        bh=dxXkvZ79qLn59RVfXz4QAs5AW2+MyxrsrN55S+jKtK0=;        b=mrrriloHJkEy4TT3wpzhEO1nvinpewLWHHExGGprhWlUU+5ME9M8w3xlaTeDcm0V0y         QYDbH6TTG2rc0vwiLuZ46Dgm3rDC0brbg/Bdh3TQRUBneOTdAW4oMMs48DSIBbbFa58j         U7GHaaXGNtsY3ah4D2x8Bv9XxPbtN1YoMEV+DFlYAStrIyyUiGXk7yotcBWqbB89/MFt         ga9f+5Rhf38/TggWLRD88fBp8u2EIDB5VwqHsX5IstX2+Y0yb+yf4sk9iiToAnIXZhiC         Ngqp3YdgLrI6+UlAvixbdB42nlxsGbBJ9WoF4dejLEIeQps47loxNuA2hBsiO1wqSE6n         3XYA=="
   },
   {
    "name": "MIME-Version",
    "value": "1.0"
   },
   {
    "name": "X-Received",
    "value": "by 10.66.182.162 with SMTP id ef2mr20318738pac.35.1445140881616; Sat, 17 Oct 2015 21:01:21 -0700 (PDT)"
   },
   {
    "name": "X-No-Auto-Attachment",
    "value": "1"
   },
   {
    "name": "Message-ID",
    "value": "<047d7bd6aa64e62f22052259149a@google.com>"
   },
   {
    "name": "Date",
    "value": "Sun, 18 Oct 2015 04:01:21 +0000"
   },
   {
    "name": "Subject",
    "value": "Infinite Elgintensity just uploaded a video"
   },
   {
    "name": "From",
    "value": "YouTube <noreply@youtube.com>"
   },
   {
    "name": "To",
    "value": "thulle3-0107@pages.plusgoogle.com"
   },
   {
    "name": "Content-Type",
    "value": "multipart/alternative; boundary=047d7bd6aa64e62f000522591497"
   }
  ],
  "body": {
   "size": 0
  },
  "parts": [
   {
    "partId": "0",
    "mimeType": "text/plain",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "size": 301,
     "data": "SW5maW5pdGUgRWx..."
    }
   },
   {
    "partId": "1",
    "mimeType": "text/html",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
     },
     {
      "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
      "value": "quoted-printable"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "size": 16884,
     "data": "DQo8aHRtbCBsYW5nPSJl..."
    }
   }
  ]
 },
 "sizeEstimate": 22314
}
```

This is how a typical message will look, and all that the various libraries does is to make it easier to work with. The `headers` will reside inside of the `payload`, and it's the `Subject`-header you are looking for.

There is no function for getting a specific header, but it's not that hard to implement:

```
function getHeader($headers, $name) {
  foreach($headers as $header) {
    if($header['name'] == $name) {
      return $header['value'];
    }
  }
}

$results = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($user);
foreach($results as $mail){
  $message = $service->users_messages->get($user, $mail['id']);
  $headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
  $subject = getHeader($headers, 'Subject');
}
```

Comment: I cannot seem to find documentation around the methods such as `getPayload` and `getPayload->getHeaders()` do you have a link to where these methods are documented?

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
 $message = $service->users_messages->get($userId, $messageId,['format' => 'metadata', 'metadataHeaders' => ['From']]);

 $headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders();

$from = $headers[0]['value']);

if($form == "My From")
```

....

I was working an mixed 2 or 3 examples and this is the result, in this case i need de Form metadata, change it for Subject and done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I read the subject of the emails

```
        $messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($user, ['q'=> 'from:foo@bar.com ']);
        foreach ($messages->getMessages() as $mail)
        {
            $message = $service->users_messages->get($user, $mail->getId());
            $headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
            $subject = array_values(array_filter($headers, function($k){
                return $k['name'] == 'Subject';
            }));
            printf("- %s\n", $subject[0]->getValue());
        }
```