# How to use the fields parameter when calling the Gmail API

Tags: api, google-api, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail API in Google Apps Script (which is basically Javascript), and I need to make as few calls to the API as possible, for efficiency and speed.

I'm using [Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) to list the messages in a user's mailbox, and the response includes an array called `messages`, and for each message it includes an `id` and a `threadId`, like so:

```
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "152b93b1111c33e2",
   "threadId": "152b922266c33e2"
  },
  {
   "id": "152b93338c98cb3",
   "threadId": "152b922266c33e2"
  } ...
```

But I need the response to include more information about each message, so that I don't have to make a separate **Users.messages:get** call for each message.

The  APIs Explorer on the [Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) page says you can use the fields parameter to "*specify which fields to include in a partial response.*"

When I click "*Use fields editor*" to select the three items I need, it fills the following in to the field:

```
messages(id,internalDate,payload)
```

Then when I execute the command, it shows that the GET command should look like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/test@test.com/messages?fields=messages(id%2CinternalDate%2Cpayload)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

However, the `messages` array in the results does not include the `internalDate` or the `payload` fields. It just includes the message `id` only, like so:

```
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "152b93b1111c33e2"
  },
  {
   "id": "152b93338c98cb3"
  } ...
```

It also does not include the `threadId` anymore, but it DOES continue to include the `threadId` if I select that as one of the fields, like so:

```
messages(id,threadId)
```

and the URL looks like this...

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/test@test.com/messages?fields=messages(id%2CthreadId)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And the result looks exactly like the first result above, where we weren't using the fields parameter.

So I know the `fields` parameter *is* actually doing something.

Thinking this might just be a limitation of the  APIs Explorer, I tried making the API call in Google Apps script, but it still does not include the fields I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there.

When listing messages, the`id` and `threadId` of each message is all you get. You then have to [get each message separately](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get).

If you e.g. just want the `internalDate` of the message, it is in this request it should be specified in the `fields` parameter.

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/152b792a91c9c391?fields=internalDate&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "internalDate": "1454778787000"
}
```

Comment: Then is the api explorer incorrect by showing all available fields? https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.history.list

Comment: @mnort9 That's the history endpoint, and you can specify `fields` with that request as well. If you e.g. want just the id of each event, you could specify `fields` with the value `history/id`

Comment: The fields parameter doesn't seem to work though when I try deeper keys within `messages`, `messagesAdded`. Only `id`, `threadId` and `labelIds` seem to work. Should the deeper keys be working or is the api explorer incorrectly making the other keys available?

Comment: @Tholle you seem to be very knowledgable of this thing. Do you by any chance know, if it is also possible to define the subject field? You can traverse with: payload/headers. But you get a lot there. Could you somehow specify to only get the header named: subject?

Comment: @Ekkstein [This answer might give some inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189329/how-can-i-read-a-gmail-subject-with-php-api). You have to look for the object in the `payload.headers` array with the `name` of `subject`.